# zsh Prompt user for autocomplete filename, including path

Tags: echo, zsh

I am trying to write a simple .zshrc command that prompts for a filename.  I would like it to autocomplete the path to the filename on tab.  vared doesn't seem to tab the file names to the window, just the folder names. Is there a simple solution to this that I am overlooking?

Here is an example.  Putting this in the terminal and tabbing through the results, I only get directories, not the contents.

```
vared -p "Enter filename, use tab for completion: " -c copy_filename
```

Comment: What do you mean with a " .zshrc command"? Do you want to run the command each time the shell starts up? Or do you mean that you want to define it in your `.zshrc` file?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying question.  I was to define it in .zshrc

Comment: When I try completion in `vared`, it completes files just fine. Can you please add the code you've written so far to your answer?

Comment: Sure.  I updated the original post with an example.